# React js : My state is not changing after onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, frontend, use-state

when I onClick, my state: changeSybmol is not changing to true but remains false.

In summary I just want my state to update to false if it is true or vice versa.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Box.css";

function Box(props) {
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [changeSymbol, setChangeSymbol] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    if (symbol === "") {
      if (!changeSymbol) {
        setChangeSymbol(true);
        setSymbol("X");
        console.log(changeSymbol);
      } else {
        setSymbol("O");
        setChangeSymbol(false);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div key={props.key} onClick={handleClick} className="box">
      {symbol}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Box;
```

Comment: Do you think it doesn't change because of the log?

Comment: I don't think so but I m not sure

Comment: @AliQumail What Dennis Vash means is that are you thinking that the state never changes because the logged value doesn't reflect it ? Try logging it outside the handleClick also.

Comment: put a ```console.log("1st if working")``` before first if statement & ```console.log("2nd if working")``` before second if statement. then you can understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first if statement and it works.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Box(props) {
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [changeSymbol, setChangeSymbol] = useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
      if (!changeSymbol) {
        setChangeSymbol(true);
        setSymbol("X");
        console.log(changeSymbol);
      } else {
        setSymbol("O");
        setChangeSymbol(false);
      }
    
  }

  return (
    <div key={props.key} onClick={handleClick} className="box">
      {symbol}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using following piece of code?

```js
if (symbol === "") {}
```

This is not allowing your code to execute futher once the symbol is set.
Remove this & your code will run fine.